# What is the cause of following error? We are getting this error while compiling Thrift C++ code

Tags: c++, cassandra, thrift

```
  thriftfs-test$ g++ -lthrift -Wall thriftfs.cpp cassandra_constants.cpp Cassandra.cpp cassandra_types.cpp -o thriftfs
    In file included from thriftfs.cpp:7:0:
    Cassandra.h:10:24: fatal error: TProcessor.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    In file included from cassandra_constants.h:10:0,
                     from cassandra_constants.cpp:7:
    cassandra_types.h:10:20: fatal error: Thrift.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    In file included from Cassandra.cpp:7:0:
    Cassandra.h:10:24: fatal error: TProcessor.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    In file included from cassandra_types.cpp:7:0:
    cassandra_types.h:10:20: fatal error: Thrift.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Soooooo, can you already exclude some possible causes so we as an unpaid service do not waste precious lifetime?

Comment: ..like where TProcessor.h is?

Comment: I somewhat have the feeling you haven't even read the error message, right?

Comment: you're missing few files... check this and the program should compile.

Answer (score 3):

You must include the path to your include directory, e.g.:

```
g++ -lthrift -I /path/to/thriftfs/include -Wall thriftfs.cpp cassandra_constants.cpp Cassandra.cpp cassandra_types.cpp -o thriftfs
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add some required include-folder/s to the g++ command line.